# Is it possible to print a structure randomly?

Tags: c

My project is simple. It is just a quiz game with user input. As for the questions and answers I used a file to keep them as a data base.
I also defined a structure:

```
typedef struct QUESTION
{
    char question[MAXCARACTERES];
    char answer1[MAXCARACTERES];
    char answer2[MAXCARACTERES];
    char answer3[MAXCARACTERES];
    char answer4[MAXCARACTERES];
} QUESTION;
```

What I wish to know if there is a possible way to print the answers randomly. Otherwise, the right one stays always in the same place.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The first step to random printing would be to turn the four answer fields into an array of answers, `char ans[4][MAXCHARACTERS];`. Then you can shuffle the array.

Comment: And remember which one was correct.

Comment: I wish there was another way, because have lots of lines written. Anyways, if not I''ll write everything from scratch.

Comment: Of course there's another way.  Generate a random permutation and print the choices in that order.

Answer (score 1):

I turned William Pursell's comment into an answer. You can't run the code because is missing the answers and some other stuff, but it should work.

```
typedef struct QUESTION
{
    char question[MAXCARACTERES];
    char answer[4][MAXCARACTERES];
} QUESTAO;

void randPerm( int *surp );

int main() {

    int surprise[4] = {0, 1, 2, 3};
    
    randPerm( surprise );
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        
        printf("%s\n", QUESTAO.answer[surprise[i]])
    }

    return 0;
}

void randPerm( int *surp )
{
    for(int i = 4; i > 1; i--) {
        
        int luck = rand() % i;
        
        int hold = surp[luck];
        surp[luck] = surp[i-1];
        surp[i-1] = hold;
    }
}
```